# Save only Option when clicking to file link

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Just a quick question. I currently have a file that you can download. i was wondering what the best approach would be on how to make the file to only save on the computer.

Because at the moment you have the option to Save or Open.

How do not give it the option to open when in a browser.

Cheers,

Comment: PHP's task is to send the header for file download and saving and opening action is completely based on (client) browser that can not be handled by PHP

Answer (score 2):

The browser handles that - not you.

So you can not do anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

That is not up to you. Browser rulz.